# Django: Can we use callback methods with F object?

Tags: python, django

Example:

```
def modify_field(param):
   #...
Model.objects.update(some_field=modify_field(F('some_field'))
```

---

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I read the question and I cannot understand what you're trying to ask. There are too many side details. May be you can reformulate it from scratch?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it in a rush because I was going to do something else. Hopefully it's readable now. I just want those few lines of code to work.

Comment: Do you want to modify all fields of all rows in some table without retrieving everything? ``F`` can be used to perform simple operations like adding +1. Otherwise there is no way I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, I basically need to make specific changes to a field and asve it but I'm guessing I can't do that with update + the F object. I guess iterating and making those changes is the only way to go (Along with the fact that I have to disconnect and reconnect signals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can have a callback method but only if you never modify the field using the F object and you meet the standards of whatever the F supports.